# Strange Behavior of ColdFusion Variable

Tags: variables, coldfusion, cfml

I am utilizing Bootstrap tabs to display some data in my ColdFusion project.  I am attempting to loop through a list of classes that are returned from the database and then getting information based on that class.  Here is the snippet of code that applies to my question:

```
<div class="tab-content" id="class-tabs-content">
    <cfset allClassIDs = ValueList(classes.class_id)>
    <cfset numOfClasses = ListLen(allClassIDs)>
    <cfloop from="1" to="#ListLen(allClassIDs)#" index="i">
        <cfset myIndex = ListGetAt(allClassIDs, i)>
        <cfoutput>
        <div class="tab-pane fade<cfif i EQ 1> show active</cfif>" id="panel-#myIndex#" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-#myIndex#">
            <!--- The following returns a cfquery --->
            <cfset items = CreateObject("component", "com.modules.reels").getInventoryByDivisionAndClass("query", division.location_id, myIndex)>
            #items.RecordCount# <-- CODE FAILS ON THIS LINE WITH MESSAGE "variable [ITEMS] doesn't exist"
        </div>
        </cfoutput>
    </cfloop>
</div>
```

UPDATE:  I tried a simpler example of what I was trying to do, and I got the same error:  variable [ITEMS] doesn't exist.  Here is the simplified code block I tried:

```
<cfset classes = CreateObject("component", "com.modules.reels").getClasses("query")>
    
<cfset ClassIDs = ValueList(classes.class_id)>
<cfloop from="1" to="#ListLen(ClassIDs)#" index="i">
    <cfset ClassID = ListGetAt(ClassIDs, i)>
    <cfoutput>
        <cfset items = CreateObject("component", "com.modules.reels").getInventoryByDivisionAndClass("query", 3, ClassID)>
        <cfdump var = "#items#">
    </cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

I do not understand what could possibly be going on here!  How can the variable not exist when I set it on the previous line and the cfset did not throw an error?  Please help!

Comment: The possibility is that the result from `getInventoryByDivisionAndClass` was `void` or `null`.

Comment: I think you may need to add the function outline as well to this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to @rrk for your comments.  As it turns out (and I feel really stupid), `getInventoryByDivisionAndClass()` was missing its `<cfreturn>` statement!